# @Cacheable in java 17

Tags: spring-boot, java-17

I have an application with spring 2.6.8, I have migrated it to 2.7.4.
And everything works correctly.

But when I have upgraded from java 11 to java 17 it gives me the following error

```
    @Cacheable(value = "datoAuxiliar", key = "{#nombre, #tipo}", unless = "#result == null")
    public DatoAuxiliar findByTipoAndSecurityDomainAndNombre(TipoDatoAuxiliar tipo, SecurityDomain securityDomain,
            String nombre);
```

-- ERROR

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tipoContratoSelectItemController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?) Builder[public abstract java.util.List com.xxx.xxx.repository.DatoAuxiliarRrhhRepository.findByTipoAndSecurityDomainAndDeletedIsNull(com.abalia.elser.domain.enumeration.TipoDatoAuxiliar,com.abalia.elser.domain.SecurityDomain)] caches=[datoAuxiliar] | key='#tipo' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='#result == null' | sync='false'


I've tried several things but they don't work for me.
Can someone help me with this problem?
Thanks.
```